# Different activation function in nnet R

Tags: neural-networks

Can different activation functions be specified for hidden and output layers for any of the R neural network packages?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, in the majority of the R neural network package, there is a parameter to control if the activation function is linear or the logistic function. In nnet the parameter is called linout= and the TRUE value means the function is linear.

Answer (score 1):

linout is only for the neuron of the output layer.
As far as I know, there is no way to choose the activation function of the hidden neurons. I'd be happy to be contradicted though.